# When using Reactor.core, does the Mono object need to explicitly subscribe if it wants to start the stream?

Tags: java, project-reactor

This is a service layer code related to Java system and device communication

```
@Service
    public class ValveOpenSender implements MessageSender<ValveOpenReply, ValveOpen> {
        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

        @Value("${mqtt.cmd-timeout}")
        private Long cmdTimeout;

        @Autowired
        private MqttGateway mqttGateway;


        @Autowired
        private DeviceService deviceService;

        @Autowired
        private DeviceOperationService deviceOperationService;


        private final Map<String, Sinks.One<ValveOpenReply>> replyProcessor = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


        @Override
        public Mono<ValveOpenReply> send(ValveOpen message) {
            return send(Mono.just(message));
        }

        @Override
        public Mono<ValveOpenReply> send(Publisher<ValveOpen> message) {
            return Mono.from(message)
                    .flatMap(msg -> {
                        Mono<ValveOpenReply> replyFlux = replyProcessor
                                .computeIfAbsent(msg.getMessageId(), ignore -> {
                                    Long operationId = sequenceGenerator.nextId();

                                    //Generate an operation record with status incomplete

                                    return Sinks.one();
                                })
                                .asMono()
                                .doOnNext(reply -> {

                                    //After receiving the device response, the operation record status changes to Completed
                                })
                                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(cmdTimeout), Mono.error(() -> new DeviceOperationException(ErrorCode.TIME_OUT)))
                                .doFinally(signal -> replyProcessor.remove(msg.getMessageId()));

                        //ValveOpen 
                        mqttGateway.sendToMqtt(msg.genTopic(), msg.encode().toString());

                        return replyFlux;
                    });
        }


        //After receiving the device response, the method will be called while executing the doOnNext method above
        public void handleReply(ValveOpenReply reply) {
            Sinks.One<ValveOpenReply> sinks = replyProcessor.get(reply.getMessageId());
            if (sinks == null) {
                logger.warn("No response message processor");
                replyProcessor.remove(reply.getMessageId());
                return;
            }
            sinks.emitValue(reply, (signalType, emitResult) -> {
                throw new DeviceOperationException(ErrorCode.valueOf("Valve opening response processing failed!"));
            });
        }
    }




 @PostMapping("/valveOpen")
    public Mono<?> valveOpen(@RequestBody ValveOpen valveOpen, HttpServletRequest request) {

        valveOpen.setClientType(ClientType.getTypeName(request.getHeader("User-Agent")));

        return valveOpenSender.send(valveOpen)
                .map(reply -> {
                    Assert.isTrue(reply.getCode().shortValue() == 0, "valve open failed");
                    return Mono.just(ResultBuilder.buildActionSuccess());
                });
    }
```

Hello everyone, this code is a valve opening interface that involves communication between the Java system and the device. The communication protocol is mqtt. The goal of the entire code is to send a valve opening command to the device, and then listen for the device's response message to change the status of the operation record to completed. In order to achieve asynchronous and non blocking effects, we introduced the Reactor. core framework. But first of all, as far as I know, the Mono object requires the entire flow to start working after calling the subscribe method.However, the use of Sinks. one to construct Mono objects in the above code did not explicitly call the subscribe method, but the entire code can run normally. I am very confused about this and hope someone can resolve my doubts. Thank you.

and by the way i have saw a few words about this,like this "Mono.from is a factory method that adapts any kind of Publisher to a Mono. It will only take the first element and ignore subsequent signals (completion, errors) if any. This transformation doesn’t require an explicit subscription since it’s cold and unicast: it starts producing signals when subscribed to and will dedicate its resources to that one consumer." but im not sure if its right

Comment: Why do you think no one subscribes to the Mono?

Comment: Because the above code does not explicitly call the subscribe method, I am confused as to why the code can still run normally without a subscription, or where there is an implicit subscription

Comment: You return the Mono, so you shouldn't and cannot subscribe to it here. A code that calls this method subscribes to the Mono

Comment: I added the controller layer code where it called the send method, but still did not perform the subscription operation.The calling method of this API is not special for front-end development, and does not involve subscription stream and other ETCs

Comment: Your control layer returns this mono. And because it's annotated with `@PostMapping` I presume it's a part of WebFlux which means that Spring makes the subscription on a POST request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If that's the case, then explain why the code is running normally

Comment: Yes, as you said, someone must subscribe to it. In your case you return your mono to the web controller, and Spring subscribes to it (otherwise it cannot produce the HTTP call result, or in other words the actual subscription is on the other side of the tcp socket)

Comment: sorry to borrow you my friend .Overall, this code is actually a logic based on the interaction between mqtt and the device side. Why introduce reactor. core and what are the benefits

Comment: @IgorArtamonov friend